# Filter json based on Lambda expression

Tags: c#, json, .net, lambda

I have this json formatted file, and want to pass it thru a lambda filter to get rid of one of the taxons where [udgået] is present

```
  [
        {
            "code": "ABSENCE_CAUSE_TYPE",
            "name": "Absence Cause Type",
            "externalId": "AbsenceCauseType",
            "taxons": [
                {
                    "code": "ABSENCECAUSE_UDP/LÆGEERKLÆRING_IKKE_AFLEVERET",
                    "externalId": "18",
                    "name": "UDP/Lægeerklæring ikke afleveret [Udgået]",
                    "rootTaxonomyCode": "ABSENCE_CAUSE_TYPE",
                    "startDate": "2012-05-01T00:00:00+02:00",
                    "endDate": "2100-07-01T00:00:00+02:00",
                    "level": 1,
                    "children": [],
                    "parentTaxonCode": null,
                    "parentTaxon": null
                },
                {
                    "code": "ABSENCECAUSE_VARIGHED_PENSIONISTER",
                    "externalId": "17",
                    "name": "Varighed pensionister",
                    "rootTaxonomyCode": "ABSENCE_CAUSE_TYPE",
                    "startDate": "2012-05-01T00:00:00+02:00",
                    "endDate": "2100-07-01T00:00:00+02:00",
                    "level": 1,
                    "children": [],
                    "parentTaxonCode": null,
                    "parentTaxon": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

but want this ending result below

```
[
    {
        "code": "ABSENCE_CAUSE_TYPE",
        "name": "Absence Cause Type",
        "externalId": "AbsenceCauseType",
        "taxons": [
            {
                "code": "ABSENCECAUSE_VARIGHED_PENSIONISTER",
                "externalId": "17",
                "name": "Varighed pensionister",
                "rootTaxonomyCode": "ABSENCE_CAUSE_TYPE",
                "startDate": "2012-05-01T00:00:00+02:00",
                "endDate": "2100-07-01T00:00:00+02:00",
                "level": 1,
                "children": [],
                "parentTaxonCode": null,
                "parentTaxon": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Anyone who can suggest a Lambda filter out any name attribute having [udgået]

Answer (score 1):

try this,this was tested in Visual studio and working properly

```
string json = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\....\test.json"))
        json = r.ReadToEnd();

var jsonParsed= JArray.Parse(json);

var taxonsToRemove= jsonParsed[0]["taxons"]
.Where(t => ((string) t["name"]).Contains("Udgået")).ToArray();
    
foreach (var item in taxonsToRemove) item.Remove();

json=jsonParsed.ToString(); // or ToObject<T>();
```

result

```
[
  {
    "code": "ABSENCE_CAUSE_TYPE",
    "name": "Absence Cause Type",
    "externalId": "AbsenceCauseType",
    "taxons": [
      {
        "code": "ABSENCECAUSE_VARIGHED_PENSIONISTER",
        "externalId": "17",
        "name": "Varighed pensionister",
        "rootTaxonomyCode": "ABSENCE_CAUSE_TYPE",
        "startDate": "2012-04-30T19:30:00-02:30",
        "endDate": "2100-06-30T19:30:00-02:30",
        "level": 1,
        "children": [],
        "parentTaxonCode": null,
        "parentTaxon": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, 

it is not working quite as i have hoped, should say i have to classes that should contain the json file, so i start with this

 var taxonomies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Taxonomy>>(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\Temp\Tax.json"));

so in fact, it is more a matter of removing data from the class Taxon.

With your suggestion i got a error saying "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type Taxonomy" pointing at "t["name"]"

Comment: @Hank Next time use the answer you get  or it is better not post your questions here . Don' t complain  when you use your own code. I am always testing my code before posting and everything is working properly.

Comment: Hi again Serge, sorry about the confusion, but running your code will have the result of

[
  {
    "code": "ABSENCECAUSE_VARIGHED_PENSIONISTER",
    "externalId": "17",
    "name": "Varighed pensionister",
    "rootTaxonomyCode": "ABSENCE_CAUSE_TYPE",
    "startDate": "2012-05-01T00:00:00+02:00",
    "endDate": "2100-07-01T00:00:00+02:00",
    "level": 1,
    "children": [],
    "parentTaxonCode": null,
    "parentTaxon": null
  }
]

First level completely disappear, this is how it originally should have looked

        "code": "ABSENCE_CAUSE_TYPE",
        ....

Comment: @Hank Thanks for a feedback, I just showed you a part of result. I updated my answer and serialized the whole result now.

Comment: Thanks Serge, seems to work a lot better :-)